# Intellij-IDE randomly switches Project-Windows

Tags: intellij-idea

Intellij-IDE can open multiple projects at once.

Those projects can be switched within the IDE with "Window"->"Next Project Window" and "Window"->"Previous Project Window".

Me and two other colleagues now have the problem that the IDE randomly switches the active project-window while we work. It is not clear, what actions are causing the random switch of the project window.

Is this a bug in intellij? does someone know how to prevent Intellij from this unnerving behavior?

Environment is:

- Intellij-IDE Ultimate: 2020.2.2
- Windows 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default keyboard shortcuts for these actions are <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> on Windows.

It could be that you hit them accidently while coding/navigating which switches the project windows. It may help if you either remove these shortcuts or change them to something different and harder to press by accident.

Comment: we have german-keyboard layout, so these shortcuts are not available.The "[" is ALTGR+7, the "]" is ALTGR+9 on the german keyboard. While those shortcuts are indeed activated in intellij-ide for those actions, it seems its impossible to produce those actions with the german keyboard

Comment: for example: today it happened, after i CTRL+C and CTRL+V (copied and pasted) some text within an editor window. After pushing CTRL-V the project windows switched to an other project.. i did not press any other keys. Sadly its not reproducible. So the next time it may as well by other keys pressed that switch the project-window. Therefore i called the thread "randomly switches..."

Comment: Please report at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA when you have more details. StackOverflow is not the best place for handling IDE bugs.

Comment: thx, i have done so: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-252684